# Object doesnot support this Property or Method for "Print" command

Tags: excel, vba, printing

Following is my code,

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Num, Sum As Integer
Sum = 0
Num = 2
Do While Num <= 20
Sum = Sum + Num
Print Sum
Num = Num + 2
Loop
Print "The sum is bla bla...."; Sum


End Sub
```

I am getting an error "Object doen't support this property or method" on the line "Print Sum". What I am missing?

Please correct me!!
 Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you expect the code to do for `Print Sum` ?

Comment: Try using `MsgBox` instead of print, and change the `;` to a `&`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Print` is not a command, method, etc.

`Debug.Print` is probably what you're looking for.

Also, you might want to use `&` instead of `;` for string concatenation.

Comment: Used Debug.Print.No error!! But nothing is Print on the form!!

Comment: `Debug.Print` only prints to the `Immediates` window, it's a debugging tool, not a way to communicate to users.  The code you have provided here does not display a form, so I'm not sure what you're talking about, unless you have more code which displays a form.  If that is the case, please **revise** your original question to include the rest of your code, so that I can suggest how to fix it :)